# python interp2d strange checkers

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am interpolating an array (2d_values) of size 105 by 109 with scipy.interpolate.interp2d.

```
 function=interp2d(2d_x_coords,2d_y_cords,2d_values)
 interpolated=float(function(2d_x_finer_coords,2d_y_fner_coords))
```

I am having an issue where interpolated comes out with proper values in most locations but in certain areas of interpolated there are checkerboards and stripes of huge positive and negative numbers  when the data is supposed to be between (0 and ~300).

2d_values is a relatively continuous field with a few places with large jumps between adjacent coordinates, and is a map projection of latitude and longitude coordinates so the coordinates are not a regular grid but are distorted as a flat map is.

[the picture on the right is 2d_values and the picture on the left is interpolated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5doo.jpg)

[this is the code used to perform this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWkiv.png)

Comment: I think we need some data to reproduce this

Comment: how do i provide the data?

Comment: Maybe just copy paste a small area of your data, that replicates the problem along with the exact code you use, so we can just copy paste and see what's going wrong

Comment: the data is in a gridded format netcdf used in the atmospheric science community and is not easily copy and pasteable. and the code is very fine tuned for working with this data format.

Comment: Well then you only might have some luck, if somebody who had the exact same problem sees your post. I can't reproduce your problem like this.

Comment: i added the actual code. the first argument is a WRFoutput file at 4km resolution.  the second is the time step to use in this file. the third is a wrfinput netcdf file

Comment: Okay sorry, i'm not familiar with the data format, maybe somebody else might be able to help

Comment: It is difficult to assess the problem without the data. Have you tried smoothing it using `kind='cubic'`? Also, have you tried using a boolean mask to filter the (maybe present) Nan values (i.e. `mask = ~np.isnan(SNOW)` )?

Comment: there are no nan values. posted solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Using griddata instead yielded great results with no issues.